# How to change ugly gray startup animation screen that KDE installed?

Tags: unity, boot, kde, startup, logo

I have Ubuntu Unity 12.04 installed.  I decided to add the KDE desktop, just to try it.  It changed the startup animation to an ugly gray screen with a squashed logo (the circular logo is way out of round) with the moving dots under it.

Is there an easy way to change it back, or maybe even better, customise it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to do it (easier than manually editing the links) is to use `update-alternatives`.

To list available alternatives:

```
update-alternatives --display default.plymouth
```

To change selected one:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

By the way, I think you can install and try some more boot animations. Search for packages named "plymouth-theme", install the ones you want and select one using the above command (I've never tried that, though.)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo rm /etc/alternatives/default.plymouth
sudo ln -s /lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.plymouth /etc/alternatives/default.plymouth
```

u have to paste it into terminal,
and then chose a ubuntu plymouth.

Comment: Yes, I see how it works.  I had no idea where to look.   Thanks for that